# get all parent records from child record

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle table similar to this

TableName:Note

```
NoteID(PK)        NoteText    ParentNoteID
1                 x           - 
2                 y           1
3                 z           2
```

Here I need to perform an like query on top of notetext say,
note.note_text like '%z%'which pulls out an third record alone.

I wish to pull the records of it's parent's as well.i.e after getting the third record,which matches through like query i need to travel back by seeing 
parentNoteID .So parent note of 3 rd record is 2 and parent record of 2 is 1.so the result should fetch
all the three record.

To extend this,if my like query matches two child records,apparently it should get all parents records of both.

Example:

```
NoteID(PK)  NoteText    ParentNoteID
1           x           -  
2           y           1
3           z           2
4           a           -
5           b           4
6           z           5
```

`note.note_text like '%z%'` should pull,all the above 6 records.

Thanks in advance
Eswar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you'd use a connect by to do this.

for example something like

```
select *
  from tbl1
 start with note_text like '%z%'
 connect by note_id = prior parent_note_id
```

would do it.

example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c6ea/1

Comment: wow ! that was awesome.Kudos.I just modified the query to serve my need select * from NOTE start with NOTE_TEXT like '%Child%' connect by prior PARENT_NOTE_ID=NOTE_ID;

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your prompt and charming response.It would be even more better if you could explain how to use two combination of connect by.  I am trying query like 'select *
  from tbl1
 start with note_text like '%z%'
 connect by prior PARENT_NOTE_ID=NOTE_ID and NOTE_ID =PARENT_NOTE_ID ' with the intention of fetching all child records if the like query matches parent thread and also for vice versa.But it works only for the first connect by statement and not considering the second.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1650864 do you mean you want to traverse down the tree as well as up it? eg `connect by nocycle noteid = prior parentnoteid or prior noteid =  parentnoteid`? eg http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9afd0/1..we have id = 10 as well in the set even though its a child of the matchind id=3 row.

Comment: Yes I meant the same exactly.Thanks a lot.You are awesome.It works perfect. So the query which I finally have  is `select * from NOTE start with NOTE_TEXT like '%add%' and note.node_type_id = '1'  connect by nocycle NOTE_ID = prior PARENT_NOTE_ID  or prior NOTE_ID=PARENT_NOTE_ID ;`